# How to get information about a cluster?

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, pbs

I'm using a Infiniband/Gigabit cluster and submit jobs using PBS. Being logged in on a new cluster, how do I get information using the bash about the number of nods and cpus/node one can use there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can get some information about the available queues by executing

```
qstat -Q
```

To get additional information about a special queue *queuename* you execute

```
qstat -Qf queuename
```